# Node.JS + mySQL -> 127.0.0.1/x is not found

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So I have one folder in which I have the server.js, login.html (the index.html) and menus.html (another page). After the user fills the login form on (login.html) and clicks on the submit button there, I want that user to be redirected to the page (menus.html) but the problem is that the server doesn't seem to recognise the page (menus.html). How can I access another page on my server?

```
  var app = require('express')();
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var db = mysql.createConnection({
        host : "127.0.0.1",
        user : "root",
        password : "",
        database : "user_data",
        port : 3306
    });
    db.connect();
    app.get('/',function(req, res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname+'/login.html');
    });
    app.get('/menus',function(req, res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname+'/menus.html');
    });
    app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: From the paths you have defined, you would get to menus.html by requesting the simple url `<server>/menus` not `/menus.html` - are you saying `/menus` is returning nothing?

Comment: You need to show us the form submit code on the client.